# Drawable in SpannableStringBuilder

Tags: android, textview, stringbuilder

I have simple SpannableStringBuilder with clicable text in TextView.
Like that:
[image]

I need to insert the small clicable picture or a button into the end of this text:
[image]

Is this possible and if so, how can I do this?

Comment: Consider adding the edit icon as a separate imagebutton, which is relative to this textview.